# Swift use String as Dictionary Keys

Tags: swift, ios8

I don't know if is possible But ... I have this code

```
var dic = Dictionary<String, String>()
var string = [button1, button2, button3]

@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject){
dic["\(string)"] = "0"
}
```

the result in My dic is

```
[button1, button2, button3]:0
```

But i want this :

```
[button1:0, button2:0, button3:0]
```

how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the apple swift dpcs example [DOC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_179):

```
var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
```

this is definitly, to access:

```
var key = "DUB"
var val = airports[key]
var val2 = airports["DUB"]
```

means you just have to use the steink directly to access a value :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample doesn't show what type `button1/2/3` are, but assuming they're `Strings` (and not buttons), you could use a loop to create the dictionary you want:

```
var button1 = "button1"
var button2 = "button2"
var button3 = "button3"

var strings = [button1, button2, button3]
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()

@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    for key in strings {
        dictionary[key] = "0"
    }
}
```

Note, you should probably use more descriptive variable names. `button` is not a good name for a `String`, and `string` is not a good name for an array of `Strings`. The name should give you a hint as to the type, and definitely not hint that it is another type. Same thing applies to the function name. `Button` sounds like an object, not an action, but a function does something, so you want it to have a name that gives that as a hint, such as `buttonTapped`.